# Could you recommend a python library or source code for reading barcodes?

Tags: python

I would like some help finding a python module that can identify a barcode within a scanned document. If anyone can help me at least come closer to finding an example of this I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar